# Cellcolor causes siunitx alignment to be ignored

Tags: tables, siunitx

With help from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543619/146362), I create the following table:

[image]

The problem is that the use of `\cellcolor` causes the `siunitx` alignment to be ignored because I enclose the contents of that cell in `{ }` (if I do not do so, the color spills over and things go mad).

How do I fix this?

---

Code for the above:

```
% these define the type of document and the look of the page
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs

% colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg3}{HTML}{ECECEC} % t gray = gray!15!white

% table-related
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{bg3}
\newcommand{\colcel}{\cellcolor{white}}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|*{3}{S|}S}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Title} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{2019} & {\colcel 2020} \\
    \hhline{~-----}
    & {1Q} & {2Q} & {3Q} & {4Q} & {\colcel 1Q} \\
    \hline
    Row 1 & 11.5 & 13 & 12.9 & 13 &  {\colcel 11.3} \\
    Row 2 & 1.3 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 &  {\colcel 1.3} \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=5, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|*{3}{S|}S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 1} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 3 & 12438 & 12009 & 12701 & 13159 & {\colcel 19696} \\
    Row 4 & 6601 & 6206 & 6745 & 7256 &  {\colcel 6665}  \\
    Row 5 & 164 & 322 & 820 & 0 &  {\colcel 2174}  \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=-2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|S|S[table-format=-1.2]|S|S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 2} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 6 & -0.8 & -0.3 & 0.2 & 0.3 &  {\colcel -0.4} \\
    Row 7 & -0.08 & -0.01 & 0.04 & 0.06 &  {\colcel -0.04}\\
    Row 8 & 0.8 & -9.9 & -5.5 & 4.3 &  {\colcel 1.0} \\
    Row 9 & 9.7 & -8.3 & -8.1 & 16.7 &  {\colcel -30.2} \\ \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different placement of the closing `}` will work: e.g: `{\colcel} 11.3` instead og `{\colcel 11.3 }`.

Background: You can place non-numeric content in a set of `{}` to "hide" it from `siunitx`. If you place the `\colcell` and the number in a set of `{}` you basically hide the number from `siunitx` preventing the alignment from yorking properly. If you just place the set of `{}` around the `\colcell` command, you only hide that command as opposed to hiding command and number.

If you plan on coloring the whole column, `\columncolor` might however be the better choice.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs

% colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg3}{HTML}{ECECEC} % t gray = gray!15!white

% table-related
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{bg3}
\newcommand{\colcel}{\cellcolor{white}}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y|S|*{3}{S|}S}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Title} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{2019} & {\colcel 2020} \\
    \hhline{~-----}
    & {1Q} & {2Q} & {3Q} & {4Q} & {\colcel 1Q} \\
    \hline
    Row 1 & 11.5 & 13 & 12.9 & 13 &  {\colcel} 11.3 \\
    Row 2 & 1.3 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 &  {\colcel} 1.3 \\
\end{tabularx}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=5, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y|S|*{3}{S|}S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 1} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 3 & 12438 & 12009 & 12701 & 13159 & {\colcel} 19696 \\
    Row 4 & 6601 & 6206 & 6745 & 7256 &  {\colcel} 6665  \\
    Row 5 & 164 & 322 & 820 & 0 &  {\colcel} 2174  \\
\end{tabularx}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=-2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y|S|*{3}{S|}S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 2} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 6 & -0.8 & -0.3 & 0.2 & 0.3 &  {\colcel} -0.4 \\
    Row 7 & -0.08 & -0.01 & 0.04 & 0.06 &  {\colcel} -0.04\\
    Row 8 & 0.8 & -9.9 & -5.5 & 4.3 &  {\colcel} 1.0 \\
    Row 9 & 9.7 & -8.3 & -8.1 & 16.7 &  {\colcel} -30.2 \\ \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `\columncolor` instead of coloring the individual cells. I don't know why the original problem was happening, but this solves it.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
% these define the type of document and the look of the page
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs

% colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg3}{HTML}{ECECEC} % t gray = gray!15!white

% table-related
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{bg3}
\newcommand{\colcel}{\cellcolor{white}}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|S|S|S|>{\columncolor{white}}S}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Title} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{2019} & { 2020} \\
    \hhline{~-----}
    & {1Q} & {2Q} & {3Q} & {4Q} & { 1Q} \\
    \hline
    Row 1 & 11.5 & 13 & 12.9 & 13 &  11.3 \\
    Row 2 & 1.3 & 1.5 & 1.5 & 1.5 &  1.3 \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=5, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|S|S|S|>{\columncolor{white}}S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 1} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 3 & 12438 & 12009 & 12701 & 13159 & 19696 \\
    Row 4 & 6601 & 6206 & 6745 & 7256 &  6665  \\
    Row 5 & 164 & 322 & 820 & 0 &  2174  \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-0.175in}

\sisetup{table-format=-2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.6cm}
\begin{tabular}{L{7cm}|S|S|S[table-format=-1.2]|S|>{\columncolor{white}}S}
    \hhline{~-----} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heading 2} \\ \hhline{~-----}
    Row 6 & -0.8 & -0.3 & 0.2 & 0.3 &  -0.4 \\
    Row 7 & -0.08 & -0.01 & 0.04 & 0.06 &  -0.04\\
    Row 8 & 0.8 & -9.9 & -5.5 & 4.3 &  1.0 \\
    Row 9 & 9.7 & -8.3 & -8.1 & 16.7 &  -30.2 \\ \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```